# change character appearance

Tags: python, replace, shift

again, I would need help and specifically with two things

im search for all this number `,` curetly resoluts

the first is how to make to
this input

```
{51, {'B', 'YZ', 'Y', 'Z', 'ZY', 'A', 'X', 'W'}}
```

this and after the number `,` I change the comma to`:`
this output im search

```
{51: {'B', 'YZ', 'Y', 'Z', 'ZY', 'A', 'X', 'W'}}
```

the result is always more so that it works even with more fields

```
{2, {'AA', 'Z', 'B', 'A'}, 3, {'B', 'D', 'C', 'AB', 'Z', 'Y', 'BA ', 'A'}, 4, {'E', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'BB', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'AC', 'A', 'CA'}, 5, {'DA', 'BC', 'E', 'W', 'CB', 'B', 'D', 'G', 'AD', 'C ', 'H', 'F', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'A'}}
```

Comment: how to change all results? commas after the number?

, at : thank you for your help

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I would like to change the character after the number in the output
`,` I change the comma to`:`
this output `{51, {'B', 'YZ', 'Y', 'Z', 'ZY', 'A', 'X', 'W'}}`  to `{51, {'B', 'YZ', 'Y', 'Z', 'ZY', 'A', 'X', 'W'}}`

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I want to change the characters after the letter
, on :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Let me know.

```py
input_str = r"{2, {'AA', 'Z', 'B', 'A'}, 3, {'B', 'D', 'C', 'AB', 'Z', 'Y', 'BA ', 'A'}, 4, {'E', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'BB', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'AC', 'A', 'CA'}, 5, {'DA', 'BC', 'E', 'W', 'CB', 'B', 'D', 'G', 'AD', 'C ', 'H', 'F', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'A'}}"
output = input_str.replace(", {", ": {")
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{2: {'AA', 'Z', 'B', 'A'}, 3: {'B', 'D', 'C', 'AB', 'Z', 'Y', 'BA ', 'A'}, 4: {'E', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'BB', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'AC', 'A', 'CA'}, 5: {'DA', 'BC', 'E', 'W', 'CB', 'B', 'D', 'G', 'AD', 'C ', 'H', 'F', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'A'}}
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace